# How to access the thank you page from the single post?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, wp-redirect

I have a thank you page on my website and I don't want anyone can access it directly so I use the below code and it working.

```
add_action('template_redirect', function() {
    // ID of the thank you page
    if (!is_page(947)) { //id of page
        return;
    }

    // coming from the form, so all is fine
    if (wp_get_referer() === get_site_url().'/contact-us/') {
        return;
    }

    // we are on thank you page
    // visitor is not coming from form
    // so redirect to home
    wp_redirect(get_home_url());
    exit;
});
```

Now, what I am doing, I have one more form on my single post and once the user submits the form then it will redirect to the thank you page but it's not going because I added the above code on my `function.php`.

So anyone knows how to access the thank you page from the single post?

Comment: Did you confirm that both your conditions are correct ```is_page(947)``` && ```wp_get_referer() === get_site_url().'/contact-us/'``` - perhaps you can use strpos on just the page permalink to make it a simpler match?

Comment: @QStudio, To be very honest, I found the above code on google and added that code in my function.php. Please add your answer if you know the best  answer.

Comment: can you try and confirm - comment out both conditions and test it, then only one at a time.. and use debugging like var_dump to help you - form experience, it might be better not to use IDs for is_page, it also accepts slugs or title.

Comment: @QStudio, If I comment is_page(947) then I am getting the error. Even not able to access my site. And If I connect wp_get_referer then it's working. But if I comment wp_get_referer then after submitting the form I am not getting the thankyou page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**Note:** WordPress deliberately misspelled the word 'referer', and thus, so did I..</sup>

If you just want to check if the referer is your `contact-us` Page or *any* single Post page, then you can first retrieve the current URL path (i.e. `example.com/<this part>/`) and then check if the path is exactly `contact-us` (or whatever is your contact Page's slug), and use [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) to find a single post having that path as the slug.

So try this, which worked for me (tested with WordPress 5.6.1):

```php
// Replace this:
if (wp_get_referer() === get_site_url().'/contact-us/') {
    return;
}

// with this:
$path = trim( parse_url( wp_get_referer(), PHP_URL_PATH ), '/' );
// If it's the contact page, don't redirect.
if ( 'contact-us' === $path ) {
    return;
} elseif ( $path ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'name'           => $path,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    ) );
    // If a post with the slug in $path was found, don't redirect.
    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
        return;
    }
}
```

- But note that the code would only work if your permalink structure (for the default `post` type) is `/%postname%/` — with or without the leading and/or trailing slashes.

And bear in mind that the referer can be easily spoofed, so you might want to consider a more reliable approach like using transients or nonces with a short lifespan.. :)

Comment: Give me sometime to implement your answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried your answer. I filled the form and submitted even I got the thank-you page also but before submitting the form I directly hit the URL domain.com/thank-you and it's opened the thank-you page. Ideally, it should not open the page until you fill the form.

Comment: No if without filling the contact form if I hit the URL domain.com/thank-you then it's redirecting to the home page and if I fill the form then it's redirecting on the thankyou page

Comment: Ah yes, sorry! And pls gnore that comment.. (which I've deleted) I'll revise my answer soon (got something else to do now)..

Comment: Sure. I'll wait for your reply.

Comment: Answer updated. :)

Comment: Apologise for the late reply. Yes, It's working as I expected. Thank you for the help. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to match the thanks page, then try to match the referer and if those conditions don't match, do nothing.

```php
add_action('template_redirect', function() {

    // match based on two condition:
    // current page is "thanks" - which I am guessing is "thanks"
    // and the referer is /contact-us/ - not this is unreliable, as referer might be empty
    if ( 
        is_page('thanks') // is page "thanks"
    ) { 
  
        // referer matches
        if( wp_get_referer() === get_site_url().'/contact-us/' ) {
             
            error_log( 'All good..' );
            return;

        } else {

            // redirect to home
            wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
            exit;

        }

    }

    // nothing to do here, as not thanks page

});
```

Comment: Getting syntax error in this line         if( wp_get_referer() === get_site_url().'/contact-us/' // referer matches ) {

Comment: I remove the // referer matches from the condition but still, I am not getting the thankyou page after filling the form from a single post but it is working from contact-us page

Comment: Try again.. small typo.

Comment: Make sure the "slug" of the thanks page is correct - change this line: is_page('thanks')

Comment: Yes, I added a thanks page slug. I have thank-you. If I submit the form from /contact-us/ then it's working but If I submit the form from a single post page then it's not working. And we can't add the slug for the single post because I have 20 single post

Comment: You only need to match positive conditions, not all the negative ones..

Comment: Right, but how can I check that?